# NetSuite ODBC connector & PowerQuery Error

Tags: odbc, powerquery, netsuite

I've had a data model set up since 1/21 and it started having issues a few weeks ago. Is anyone experiencing these issues, especially someone also using the NetSuite ODBC?

I'm dead in the water if I can't get this fixed. In PowerQuery, I can no longer refresh the previews and edit the queries, either.

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

[image]

In PowerQuery, the refresh never loads and generates the following error:
[image]

Error with full details:
Feedback Type:
Frown (Error)

```
Error Message:
Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Stack Trace:
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.EvaluationHost.OnException(IEngineHost engineHost, IMessageChannel channel, ExceptionMessage message)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.MessageHandlers.TryDispatch(IMessageChannel channel, Message message)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.MessageHandlers.Dispatch(IMessageChannel channel, Message message)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.ChannelMessenger.ChannelMessageHandlers.TryDispatch(IMessageChannel channel, Message message)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.MessageHandlers.Dispatch(IMessageChannel channel, Message message)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.Interface.IMessageChannelExtensions.WaitFor[T](IMessageChannel channel)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.RemotePreviewValueSource.PreviewValueSource.WaitFor(Func`1 condition, Boolean disposing)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.RemotePreviewValueSource.PreviewValueSource.get_SmallValue()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Evaluator.Interface.TracingPreviewValueSource.get_SmallValue()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.Analysis.PackageDocumentAnalysisInfo.PackagePartitionAnalysisInfo.SetPreviewValue(EvaluationResult2`1 result, Func`1 getStaleSince, Func`1 getSampled)

Stack Trace Message:
Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Invocation Stack Trace:
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionExtensions.GetCurrentInvocationStackTrace()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.FeedbackErrorInfo..ctor(String message, Exception exception, Nullable`1 stackTraceInfo, String messageDetail)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.IUIHostExtensions.RaiseErrorDialog(IUIHost uiHost, IWindowHandle activeWindow, FeedbackPackageInfo feedbackPackageInfo, Exception e, LocalizedString dialogTitle, LocalizedString dialogMessage, Boolean useGDICapture)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.Native.NativeUserFeedbackServices.ReportException(IWindowHandle activeWindow, IUIHost uiHost, FeedbackPackageInfo feedbackPackageInfo, Exception e, Boolean useGDICapture)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.UnexpectedExceptionHandler.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<HandleException>b__0()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.UnexpectedExceptionHandler.HandleException(Exception e)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionHandlerExtensions.HandleExceptions(IExceptionHandler exceptionHandler, Action action)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackDo(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackHelper(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallback(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbacks()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.LocalModalMessageLoop(Form form)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Windows.DialogWindowBase.ShowModal(IWindowHandle windowHandle)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.WebDialogs.WebDialog.<>n__0(IWindowHandle owner)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.WindowManager.ShowModal[T](T dialog, Func`1 showModalFunction)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.QueriesEditorWindow.ShowModal(ILegacyUIHost uiHost, FormulaHistoryManager formulaHistoryManager, ApplicationTracingHost applicationTracingHost, ExcelServices excelServices, ConnectionManager connectionManager, DialogManager dialogManager, FillManager fillManager, PackageManager packageManager, IFileDialogManager fileDialogManager, ITelemetryService telemetryService, IWindowHandle ownerWindow, IWorkbookIdentity workbookIdentity, QueriesEditorParameters queriesEditorParameters, Queries queries)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.UI.LegacyMashupClientUIServices.ShowQueriesEditorWindow(IWindowHandle ownerWindow, IWorkbookIdentity workbookIdentity, QueriesEditorParameters queriesEditorParameters, IQueryServices queryServices, Queries queries)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.QueriesEditorWindowManager.ShowModalQueriesEditorWindow(IWindowHandle ownerWindow, IWorkbookIdentity workbookIdentity, QueriesEditorParameters queriesEditorParameters, Queries queries, IUndoScope undoScope)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.QueriesEditorWindowManager.<>c__DisplayClass14_1.<ShowModalQueriesEditorWindow>b__1(IUndoScope undoScope)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.Shim.NativeWorkbookStorageServices.Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.Shim.IDeferredStorageInvoker.InvokeDeferredStorageAction(IWorkbook workbook, Action action)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.Shim.NativeCoAuthServices.InvokeCoauthAction(IWorkbook workbook, UndoableActionType actionType, Action action)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.Shim.NativeUndoServices.InvokeUndoableAction(IWorkbook workbook, UndoableActionType actionType, Action`1 action)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.Shim.NativeCoAuthServices.NotifyGetDataPresence(IWorkbook workbook, Action action)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.QueriesEditorWindowManager.ShowModalQueriesEditorWindow(IWindowHandle ownerWindow, IWorkbookIdentity workbookIdentity, QueriesEditorParameters queriesEditorParameters, Queries queries)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.DialogManager.TryShowModalEditor(IWindowHandle ownerWindow, IWorkbook workbook, Query query, Boolean isNewQuery, Boolean navigatorExpanded)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.ExcelQueryServices.<>c__DisplayClass35_0.<EditQuery>b__0(IWorkbook workbook)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.ExcelQueryServices.TryInvokeOnWorkbook(Action`1 action)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.Shim.NativeCoAuthServices.NotifyGetDataPresence(IWorkbook workbook, Action action)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.TaskPaneControls.TaskPaneControl.NotifyGetDataPresence(Action action)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Windows.ContextMenuRenderer.<>c__DisplayClass22_0.<CreateMenuItem>b__1()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionHandlerExtensions.HandleExceptions(IExceptionHandler exceptionHandler, Action action)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.RaiseEvent(Object key, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


Supports Premium Content:
True

Formulas:


section Section1;

shared #"Transaction Accounting Line" = let
    Source = Odbc.DataSource("dsn=NetSuite2", [HierarchicalNavigation=true]),
    #"Iovance Biotherapeutics, Inc__Database" = Source{[Name="Iovance Biotherapeutics, Inc_",Kind="Database"]}[Data],
    #"Lion Bio - Controller (without JE Approval)_Schema" = #"Iovance Biotherapeutics, Inc__Database"{[Name="Lion Bio - Controller (without JE Approval)",Kind="Schema"]}[Data],
    TransactionAccountingLine_Table = #"Lion Bio - Controller (without JE Approval)_Schema"{[Name="TransactionAccountingLine",Kind="Table"]}[Data],
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(TransactionAccountingLine_Table,{"amountpaid", "amountunpaid", "credit", "debit", "glauditnumber", "glauditnumberdate", "glauditnumbersequence", "glauditnumbersetby", "paymentamountunused", "paymentamountused", "transactionline", "amount"}),
    #"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"account", "Account ID #"}, {"exchangerate", "Exchange Rate ID #"}, {"netamount", "Net Amount"}, {"posting", "Posting T-F"}, {"transaction", "Transaction ID #"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns1";

shared #"Transaction Line" = let
    Source = Odbc.DataSource("dsn=NetSuite2", [HierarchicalNavigation=true]),
    #"Iovance Biotherapeutics, Inc__Database" = Source{[Name="Iovance Biotherapeutics, Inc_",Kind="Database"]}[Data],
    #"Lion Bio - Controller (without JE Approval)_Schema" = #"Iovance Biotherapeutics, Inc__Database"{[Name="Lion Bio - Controller (without JE Approval)",Kind="Schema"]}[Data],
    transactionLine_Table = #"Lion Bio - Controller (without JE Approval)_Schema"{[Name="transactionLine",Kind="Table"]}[Data],
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(transactionLine_Table,{"actualshipdate", "billeddate", "billingschedule", "billvariancestatus", "cleared", "cleareddate", "commitinventory", "commitmentfirm", "costestimate", "costestimaterate", "costestimatetype",  "custcol1", "custcol_5892_eutriangulation", "custcol_adjustment_field", "custcol_adjustment_tax_code", "custcol_counterparty_vat", "custcol_country_of_origin_code", "custcol_country_of_origin_name", "custcol_emirate", "custcol_establishment_code", "custcol_expense_code_of_supply", "custcol_far_trn_relatedasset", "custcol_nature_of_transaction_codes", "custcol_nondeductible_account", "custcol_po_line_id", "custcol_sii_annual_prorate", "custcol_sii_exempt_line_details", "custcol_sii_service_date", "custcol_statistical_procedure_purc", "custcol_statistical_procedure_sale", "custcol_statistical_value", "custcol_statistical_value_base_curr", "debitforeignamount", "donotdisplayline", "eliminate", "estgrossprofit", "estgrossprofitpercent",  "oldcommitmentfirm", "orderpriority", "paymentmethod",  "processedbyrevcommit", "requestnote", "taxline", "transactiondiscount", "transferorderitemlineid", "units", "vsoeisestimate", "matchbilltoreceipt", "location", "linesequencenumber", "kitcomponent",  "item", "isbillable", "iscogs", "iscustomglline", "isfullyshipped",  "isinventoryaffecting", "fulfillable",  "hasfulfillableitems", "expectedreceiptdate", "mainline", "transactionlinetype", "category"}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Columns", each true),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{{"department", "department #"}, {"expenseaccount", "expenseaccount 3 digit"}}),
    #"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Renamed Columns",{{"id", "ID # 0-698"}, {"transaction", "transaction ID #"}, {"class", "Project Code ID #"},  {"department #", "Transaction Dept ID #"}, {"documentnumber", "Transaction Doc Number"}, {"entity", "Transaction Entity ID #"}, {"expenseaccount 3 digit", "Exp Account ID #"}, {"linelastmodifieddate", "Transaction Line Last Modified Date"}, {"memo", "Transaction Memo"}, {"netamount", "Transaction Net Amount"}}),
    #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Renamed Columns1", each true),
    #"Renamed Columns2" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Filtered Rows1",{{"rate", "Transaction Line Exchange Rate"}, {"transaction ID #", "Transaction Line ID #"}, {"uniquekey", "Transaction Line Unique Key #"},  {"Transaction Dept ID #", "Transaction Line Dept ID #"}, {"Transaction Doc Number", "Transaction Line Doc Number"}, {"Project Code ID #", "Transaction Line Project Code ID #"}, {"Transaction Entity ID #", "Transaction Line Entity ID #"}, {"Exp Account ID #", "Transaction Line Exp Account ID #"}, {"ID # 0-698", "Transaction Line ID # 0-698"}, {"Transaction Memo", "Transaction Line Memo"}, {"Transaction Net Amount", "Transaction Line Net Amount"}, {"createdfrom", "Source PO"}}),
    #"Removed Columns3" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Renamed Columns2",{"creditforeignamount", "foreignamount", "foreignamountpaid", "foreignamountunpaid", "foreignpaymentamountunused", "foreignpaymentamountused", "fxamountlinked"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns3",{{"Transaction Line Last Modified Date", type date}})
in
    #"Changed Type";

shared #"Accounting Period" = let
    Source = Odbc.DataSource("dsn=NetSuite2", [HierarchicalNavigation=true]),
    #"Iovance Biotherapeutics, Inc__Database" = Source{[Name="Iovance Biotherapeutics, Inc_",Kind="Database"]}[Data],
    #"Lion Bio - Controller (without JE Approval)_Schema" = #"Iovance Biotherapeutics, Inc__Database"{[Name="Lion Bio - Controller (without JE Approval)",Kind="Schema"]}[Data],
    accountingPeriod_Table = #"Lion Bio - Controller (without JE Approval)_Schema"{[Name="accountingPeriod",Kind="Table"]}[Data],
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(accountingPeriod_Table,{"alllocked", "allownonglchanges", "aplocked", "arlocked", "closed", "isadjust", "isinactive", "isposting", "isquarter", "isyear", "parent"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"closedondate", "Closed On Date"}, {"enddate", "End Date"}, {"id", "Period ID #"}, {"lastmodifieddate", "Last Modified Date"}, {"periodname", "Period Name"}, {"startdate", "Start Date"}}),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Renamed Columns",{"Closed On Date", "Last Modified Date"}),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Removed Columns1"),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Duplicates", each not Text.StartsWith([Period Name], "Q") and not Text.StartsWith([Period Name], "FY"))
in
    #"Filtered Rows";

shared Account = let
    Source = Odbc.DataSource("dsn=NetSuite2", [HierarchicalNavigation=true]),
    #"Iovance Biotherapeutics, Inc__Database" = Source{[Name="Iovance Biotherapeutics, Inc_",Kind="Database"]}[Data],
    #"Lion Bio - Controller (without JE Approval)_Schema" = #"Iovance Biotherapeutics, Inc__Database"{[Name="Lion Bio - Controller (without JE Approval)",Kind="Schema"]}[Data],
    Account_Table = #"Lion Bio - Controller (without JE Approval)_Schema"{[Name="Account",Kind="Table"]}[Data],
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(Account_Table,{"billableexpensesacct", "cashflowrate", "category1099misc", "class", "currency", "custrecord_acct_bank_account_number", "custrecord_cps_bdc_lastupdatedbyimp_acc", "custrecord_fam_account_showinfixedasset", "eliminate", "generalrate", "includechildren", "inventory", "isinactive", "issummary", "location", "parent", "reconcilewithmatching", "revalue", "sspecacct", "subsidiary", "unit", "unitstype"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"accountsearchdisplayname", "Account & # Display Name"}, {"accountsearchdisplaynamecopy", "Account Display Name"}, {"acctnumber", "Account number"}, {"accttype", "Account Type"}, {"department", "Department ID #"}, {"description", "Acct Description"}}),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Renamed Columns",{"displaynamewithhierarchy", "fullname"}),
    #"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns1",{{"externalid", "Account External ID #"}, {"id", "Account ID #"}, {"lastmodifieddate", "Last Modified Date"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns1";

shared Budget = let
    Source = Odbc.DataSource("dsn=NetSuite2", [HierarchicalNavigation=true]),
    #"Iovance Biotherapeutics, Inc__Database" = Source{[Name="Iovance Biotherapeutics, Inc_",Kind="Database"]}[Data],
    #"Lion Bio - Controller (without JE Approval)_Schema" = #"Iovance Biotherapeutics, Inc__Database"{[Name="Lion Bio - Controller (without JE Approval)",Kind="Schema"]}[Data],
    budgets_Table = #"Lion Bio - Controller (without JE Approval)_Schema"{[Name="budgets",Kind="Table"]}[Data],
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(budgets_Table,{{"account", "Budget Account ID #"}, {"category", "Budget Category ID #"}, {"class", "Budget Project Code ID #"}, {"currency", "Budget Currency ID #"}, {"customer", "Budget Customer ID #"}, {"department", "Budget Department ID #"}, {"id", "Budget ID #"}, {"item", "Budget Item"}, {"location", "Budget Location ID #"}, {"subsidiary", "Budget Subsidiary ID #"}, {"total", "Budget Total $"}, {"year", "Budget Year"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns";

shared #"Budgets Machine" = let
    Source = Odbc.DataSource("dsn=NetSuite2", [HierarchicalNavigation=true]),
    #"Iovance Biotherapeutics, Inc__Database" = Source{[Name="Iovance Biotherapeutics, Inc_",Kind="Database"]}[Data],
    #"Lion Bio - Controller (without JE Approval)_Schema" = #"Iovance Biotherapeutics, Inc__Database"{[Name="Lion Bio - Controller (without JE Approval)",Kind="Schema"]}[Data],
    budgetsMachine_Table = #"Lion Bio - Controller (without JE Approval)_Schema"{[Name="budgetsMachine",Kind="Table"]}[Data],
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(budgetsMachine_Table,{"accountingPeriod", "budgets"})
in
    #"Removed Columns";

shared Transaction = let
    Source = Odbc.DataSource("dsn=NetSuite2", [HierarchicalNavigation=true]),
    #"Iovance Biotherapeutics, Inc__Database" = Source{[Name="Iovance Biotherapeutics, Inc_",Kind="Database"]}[Data],
    #"Lion Bio - Controller (without JE Approval)_Schema" = #"Iovance Biotherapeutics, Inc__Database"{[Name="Lion Bio - Controller (without JE Approval)",Kind="Schema"]}[Data],
    transaction_Table = #"Lion Bio - Controller (without JE Approval)_Schema"{[Name="transaction",Kind="Table"]}[Data],
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(transaction_Table,{"actionitem", "actualshipdate", "billingaddress", "billingstatus", "bulkprocsubmission", "buyingreason", "buyingtimeframe", "currency", "custbody1", "custbody2", "custbody3", "custbody4", "custbody6", "custbody7", "custbody_11187_pref_entity_bank", "custbody_11724_bank_fee", "custbody_11724_pay_bank_fees", "custbody_2663_reference_num", "custbody_4110_customregnum", "custbody_4599_mx_operation_type", "custbody_4599_sg_import_permit_num", "custbody_9997_autocash_assertion_field", "custbody_9997_is_for_ep_dd", "custbody_9997_is_for_ep_eft", "custbody_9997_pfa_record", "custbody_adjustment_journal", "custbody_cash_register", "custbody_counterparty_vat", "custbody_country_of_origin", "custbody_cps_bdc_amount", "custbody_cps_bdc_bank_account", "custbody_cps_bdc_lastupdatedbyimport", "custbody_cps_bdc_mm_type", "custbody_cps_bdc_online_sentpay_info", "custbody_cps_bdc_paid_via_bdc", "custbody_cps_bdc_paidbillupdated", "custbody_cps_bdc_payment_account", "custbody_cps_bdc_payment_method", "custbody_date_lsa", "custbody_date_of_taxable_supply", "custbody_delivery_terms", "custbody_document_date", "custbody_esc_campaign_category", "custbody_establishment_code", "custbody_fam_jrn_is_reversal", "custbody_fam_jrn_reversal_date", "custbody_fam_jrn_reversal_no", "custbody_fam_lp_asset", "custbody_fam_lp_assetdesc", "custbody_fam_lp_assetprop", "custbody_fam_lp_company", "custbody_fam_lp_contract", "custbody_fam_lp_contractnum", "custbody_fam_lp_financelease", "custbody_fam_lp_gainonmod", "custbody_fam_lp_intexpense", "custbody_fam_lp_leaseliability", "custbody_fam_lp_rightofuse", "custbody_fam_lp_startdate", "custbody_fam_lp_totalinterest", "custbody_fam_lp_totalleaseliab", "custbody_fam_lp_totalleasepayment", "custbody_fam_lp_totalnpv", "custbody_fam_lp_totalprincipal", "custbody_fam_specdeprjrn_shortage", "custbody_fam_specdeprjrn_specialdepr", "custbody_itr_doc_number", "custbody_itr_nexus", "custbody_link_lsa", "custbody_link_name_lsa", "custbody_mode_of_transport", "custbody_my_import_declaration_num", "custbody_nexus_notc", "custbody_nondeductible_processed", "custbody_nondeductible_ref_genjrnl", "custbody_nondeductible_ref_tran", "custbody_notc", "custbody_refno_originvoice", "custbody_regime_code", "custbody_regime_code_of_supply", "custbody_report_timestamp", "custbody_sii_accounting_date", "custbody_sii_article_61d", "custbody_sii_article_72_73", "custbody_sii_correction_type", "custbody_sii_exempt_details", "custbody_sii_external_reference", "custbody_sii_intra_txn_type", "custbody_sii_invoice_date", "custbody_sii_is_third_party", "custbody_sii_issued_inv_type", "custbody_sii_land_register", "custbody_sii_not_reported_in_time", "custbody_sii_operation_date", "custbody_sii_orig_bill", "custbody_sii_orig_invoice", "custbody_sii_property_location", "custbody_sii_received_inv_type", "custbody_sii_ref_no", "custbody_sii_registration_code", "custbody_sii_registration_msg", "custbody_sii_registration_status", "custbody_sii_spcl_scheme_code_purchase", "custbody_sii_spcl_scheme_code_sales", "custbody_stc_amount_after_discount", "custbody_stc_payment_transaction_id", "custbody_stc_tax_after_discount", "custbody_stc_total_after_discount", "custbody_transaction_region", "daysopen", "daysoverduesearch", "duedate", "email", "estgrossprofit", "estgrossprofitpercent", "expectedclosedate", "fax", "firmed",  "foreignpaymentamountunused", "foreignpaymentamountused",  "fulfillmenttype", "includeinforecast", "incoterm", "intercoadj", "intercostatus", "intercotransaction", "isfinchrg",  "journaltype", "linkedtrackingnumberlist", "memdoc", "message", "nextapprover", "nexus", "opportunity", "ordpicked", "ordreceived", "otherrefnum", "paymenthold", "paymentmethod", "paymentoption", "posting", "printedpickingticket", "probability", "projectedtotal", "rangehigh", "rangelow", "revision", "salesreadiness", "startdate",  "terms", "title", "tosubsidiary", "totalcostestimate", "trackingnumberlist", "transactionnumber", "transferlocation", "useitemcostastransfercost", "userevenuearrangement", "visibletocustomer", "void", "voided", "website", "weightedtotal", "winlossreason", "shippingaddress", "source", "sourcetransaction", "shipcomplete", "shipdate", "nextbilldate"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"abbrevtype", "Trans Type"}}),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Renamed Columns",{"accountbasednumber", "entitystatus", "externalid"}),
    #"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns1",{{"entity", "Vendor ID #"}, {"Trans Type", "Transaction Type"}, {"approvalstatus", "Approval Status"}, {"closedate", "Close Date"}, {"createdby", "Created By ID #"}, {"createddate", "Created Date"}, {"employee", "Employee ID #"}, {"enddate", "End Date"}, {"estimatedbudget", "Estimated Budget"}, {"id", "Transaction ID #"}, {"isbudgetapproved", "Is Budget Approved"}, {"isreversal", "Is Reversal"}, {"lastmodifiedby", "Last Modified By"}, {"lastmodifieddate", "Last Modified Date"}, {"memo", "Transaction Memo"}, {"number", "Transction Number"}, {"postingperiod", "Posting Period"}, {"recordtype", "Transaction Record Type"}, {"reversal", "Reversal"}, {"reversaldate", "Transaction Reversal Date"}, {"status", "Transaction Status"}, {"trandate", "Transaction Date"}, {"trandisplayname", "Transaction Name"}, {"tranid", "Transaction #"}, {"type", "Trans Type"}}),
    #"Removed Columns2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Renamed Columns1",{"typebaseddocumentnumber"})
in
    #"Removed Columns2";

shared Vendor = let
    Source = Odbc.DataSource("dsn=NetSuite2", [HierarchicalNavigation=true]),
    #"Iovance Biotherapeutics, Inc__Database" = Source{[Name="Iovance Biotherapeutics, Inc_",Kind="Database"]}[Data],
    #"Lion Bio - Controller (without JE Approval)_Schema" = #"Iovance Biotherapeutics, Inc__Database"{[Name="Lion Bio - Controller (without JE Approval)",Kind="Schema"]}[Data],
    Vendor_Table = #"Lion Bio - Controller (without JE Approval)_Schema"{[Name="Vendor",Kind="Table"]}[Data],
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(Vendor_Table,{"accountnumber", "altemail", "altphone", "balance", "balanceprimary", "comments",  "creditlimit", "currency", "custentity_11724_pay_bank_fees", "custentity_2663_eft_file_format", "custentity_2663_email_address_notif", "custentity_2663_payment_method", "custentity_4599_sg_uen", "custentity_cps_bdc_lastupdatedbyimport", "custentity_cps_bdc_vendor_info", "custentity_cps_bdc_vendor_name", "custentity_my_brn", "custentity_sii_id", "custentity_sii_id_type", "custentity_tax_contact", "custentity_tax_contact_first", "custentity_tax_contact_last", "custentity_tax_contact_middle", "custentity_tax_reg_no", "custentityvendor_approval_status", "custentityvendor_next_approver_id", "defaultbankaccount", "defaultbillingaddress", "defaultshippingaddress", "duplicate", "email", "emailpreference", "emailtransactions"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"id", "Vendor ID #"}}),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Renamed Columns",{"incoterm", "isautogeneratedrepresentingentity", "isinactive", "isjobresourcevend", "isperson", "lastmodifieddate", "lastname", "entitynumber", "entitytitle", "datecreated", "expenseaccount", "externalid", "fax", "faxtransactions", "firstname", "homephone", "middlename", "mobilephone", "payablesaccount", "phone", "printoncheckas", "printtransactions", "purchaseorderamount", "purchaseorderquantity", "purchaseorderquantitydiff", "receiptamount", "receiptquantity", "receiptquantitydiff", "representingsubsidiary", "rolesforsearch", "salutation", "subsidiaryedition", "terms", "title", "unbilledorders", "unbilledordersprimary", "url", "workcalendar"}),
    #"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns1",{{"altname", "Vendor Name"}}),
    #"Removed Columns2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Renamed Columns1",{"companyname"}),
    #"Renamed Columns2" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns2",{{"category", "Vendor Category ID #"}, {"contact", "Vendor Contact"}, {"contactlist", "Vendor Contact List"}}),
    #"Removed Columns3" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Renamed Columns2",{"entityid", "legalname"})
in
    #"Removed Columns3";

shared employee = let
    Source = Odbc.DataSource("dsn=NetSuite2", [HierarchicalNavigation=true]),
    #"Iovance Biotherapeutics, Inc__Database" = Source{[Name="Iovance Biotherapeutics, Inc_",Kind="Database"]}[Data],
    #"Lion Bio - Controller (without JE Approval)_Schema" = #"Iovance Biotherapeutics, Inc__Database"{[Name="Lion Bio - Controller (without JE Approval)",Kind="Schema"]}[Data],
    employee_Table = #"Lion Bio - Controller (without JE Approval)_Schema"{[Name="employee",Kind="Table"]}[Data]
in
    employee_Table;
```

Comment: What driver / connection string are you using?

Comment: Do you have any possibility to check/test the ODBC connection using another app than Excel (e.g. Access)? Or are there any changes in the database? Or you changed your login credentials? Or (temporary) network issues in between? The error code states there is either no access to, no database or no table present.